# Short run of propane to stove and tankless WH

Tags: propane, tankless

I have a small stove with a propane conversion kit and a 3gpm propane tankless water heater. This is for a small MIL suite ~650 sqft. Both the stove and the water heater are on the same exterior wall, about 6ft apart.  The wall has no windows or other openings. I want to place 2 20lb BBQ tanks outside on that wall. I've been searching for information about connecting a changeover valve like used in RVs to them.  From there, a short run of black pipe, through the wall to street elbows and a shut-off valve at each appliance. Both appliances have 1/2" connections.  I can't seem to find specific information about connecting the tanks to the black pipe. What do I use?  I am going to have this pressure tested and inspected after I'm done.

Comment: 40lbs of propane isn't a whole lot of propane, especially for a tankless heater!

Comment: I did the calculation on the tankless alone. 430k BTU tank and 75k BTU tankless (430000/75000/.25). A single tank should last about 23 days given a 15 minute shower once a day. I do not expect this to be used heavily. Some reviewers said they get between 45 and 60 days on a 20lb tank. The 75k BTU/hr is the max 45 degree rise at 3.4 GPM. A shower uses 2.5 GPM and we have between 62-72 degree water year round.

Comment: Ah -- good that you ran the numbers -- the duty cycle of your operation is what makes this different from the previous cases I've seen on this Stack.

Comment: After more than a year of running on BBQ tanks, I can say that this has worked out well.  The propane powers both a stove and the tankless.  Washing dishes, cooking, and showering is about a month per tank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up getting was a hose with a regulator.  On the other end was a 3/8" flare female.  I found a 3/8" flare male to 1/2" MIP (Male iron pipe).  I used a 1/2" coupling to a 3" nipple to a tee.  From there it went to each of the 1/2" nipples through the wall, to a street elbow, and finally to a gas shutoff valve.  This is the basic setup now.  I'll have to order a changeover for the 2nd tank.

```
street elbow => shutoff         street elbow => shutoff
|              ---------        |
|                wall           |
|              ---------        |
|__________________Tee__________|
                    |
                    |
              1/2" coupling
                    |
        3/8" male flare to 1/2" MIP
Regulator with hose 5/8" female to 3/8" female
              propane tank
```